# Post comment with custom CodeBuild build information to GitHub PR

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codebuild

A CodeBuild build gets triggered by a new commit in GitHub PR via webhook. The build uses a buildspec.yml file for steps it needs to run. Then it automatically posts a fail/success status back to the PR.

Is it possible to send a comment back to the PR after the build completes with some custom information, such as version, link to the version, link to the logs, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following to the shell script run from buildspec:

```
curl -s -H "Authorization: token ${TOKEN}" \
  -X POST -d "{\"body\": \"Sample Comment" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/${OWNER}/${REPO}/issues/${PR_NUMBER}/comments"
```